# Derivation of lagrange equation in classical mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, differentiation, calculus

I'm currently working on classical mechanics and I am stuck in a part of the derivation of the lagrange equation with generalized coordinates. I just cant figure it out and don't know if it's just basic mathematics or a physics assumption. I hope someone can explain this step to me. I don't understand the transition from the terms involving the partial derivative to the kinetic energy term.

[image]

Comment: Use the chain rule of differentiation of a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the derivative (don't forger the inner derivative):
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{q}_{j}}\left(\frac{1}{2}m_{i}v_{i}^{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}m_{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{q}_{j}}v_{i}^{2}=m_{i}\boldsymbol{v}_{i}\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{v}_{i}}{\partial\dot{q}_{j}}$$